# Breakpoints not working correct

Tags: android, eclipse, breakpoints

This morning my breakpoints was working fine.

Now when you add a breakpoint there is a line through the breakpoint "dot". When code is running it skips the breakpoints. (almost a "\" through the breakpoint "dot")

Both the breakpoint and the line are blue/grey in color

Not sure what I did that it is not working.

I do have the following line in manifest

`android:debuggable="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for Run > Skip All Breakpoints